# Does this analysis make sense and can anyone provide relevent references?

Tags: regression, logistic, confidence-interval, generalized-estimating-equations, mortality

I have a GEE logistic regression model that I've built that predicts that probability of mortality given a rather extensive set of covariates.  I wanted to write here as a sanity check of sorts to make sure that what I'm doing seems sensible and to get some clarification on how to go about obtaining confidence intervals for this analysis.  Allow me to explain:

The purpose of the study is to examine the relationship between a continuous intervention variable (which is a percentage in the range of 0 to 100%) on mortality while controlling for a number of other covariates.  I build a model in GEE due to the data having some dependencies and repeated patient visits.  After building the model, I made predictions on the datasets, holding all the variables in my model constant with the exception of the intervention, which I initially set fixed at 0% (and later to 10%, 20%, . .  100%) for every patient in the dataset.  This gave me predictions of mortality for each individual.  Now, within each of four risk categories (a categorical variable that appears in the model), I obtained the mean predicted mortality rate, the mean predicted upper 95% confidence interval and the mean predicted lower 95% confidence interval.  So in the end, I have four risk categories, each with a mean predicted mortality and mean 95% upper and lower confidence bounds. This processed was repeated once for each 10% increment of my intervention variable.  My intention was to essentially look at the all the patient characteristics and form a counterfactual where the only thing I change is the intervention, and made predictions to see, hypothetically, what could we expect if, all else being constant, the intervention had actually been 10% (or 20%, 30%, etc.) instead of what was actually observed.

So my questions are: (1)  Does this sound like a sound/reasonable approach and if so (2) Is it appropriate to simply take the mean of the individual 95% upper and lower confidence intervals to find confidence intervals for each level of categorical risk factor and intervention percentage?  If not, how else can I go about this, without having to separately tabulate the confidence intervals for very specific linear combinations of an extensive list of predictors?  Essentially, I'm trying to avoid having to say something like, for those with high oxygen saturation levels, having never experienced cancer before, who were previously admitted for the same condition, and high cancer risk, the confidence interval is (x, y).  In other words, I'd like to be able to just say something about the the intervention in each of the groups, across all patients reflective of their other current clinical characteristics en masse.

UPDATED:
I have read a bit about marginal means and this seems close to what I'm trying to do, but not quite.  Instead of using marginal means, I'm trying to obtain the mean predicted mortality across the entire population under study.  It seems simultaneous confidence intervals are quite easy to provide for marginal means, but I'm not sure how to go about obtaining confidence intervals for the methodology I've described, other than bootstrap methods.  Any additional advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a simulation based on historic data to me. Indeed, you could generate "random" draws by varying the model parameters and inputs using a monte carlo-type approach. Given that, an empirical estimate of the confidence intervals could be developed from the output.

Comment: Thanks, @DJohnson.  Yes, I was thinking about bootstrapping a confidence band and then using this for the 95% confidence band after giving this some more thought.  I don't think it's appropriate for me to be simply taking the mean of the upper and lower confidence intervals of the individual predictions.  I'd love to hear other responses too!